# Writing strings that come from a dictionary to multiple files while opening the files least number of times in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = [{'account': 'xyz', 'email':'abc@xyz.com'}, {'account': 'xyz', 'email':'zxc@vbn.com'}, {'account': 'qwe', 'email':'rty@uio.com'}, ..., ...]
```

For each of the 'accounts' on the dictionary, I want to create a CSV file and the CSV file should have each of the emails belonging to the same account. So, there are multiple files for multiple accounts. For example, the CSV file xyz.csv should have:

abc@xyz.com

zxc@vbn.com

So far, I have tried creating multiple strings (as many as the number of items the dictionary has):

```
for i in dict:
    globals()[f'list_{i}'] = ""
```

and opened the files and wrote every time for each element.
However, I am trying to see if I can write it to strings first and then write it to the files in a single loop.
The accounts are already sorted.

Please help.
**the Main objective is to open and write to the files as few times as possible.  **

Comment: Sorting the list by account and then using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) seems very apropos…

Comment: The accounts are already sorted, @deceze

Comment: your `dict` is a list - it hides the build in `dict()` and for your probelm there are hundreds of posts operating on lists wanting to `groupby` some key and collect all values ... what did you research?`Why is it important to not open/close files multiple times? Anything nefarious going on with all those accounts and emails?

Comment: And please don't create variable variables. What problem is having many `list_{i}` solving…?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, in a scenario where it will be hosted and operated over the cloud, that many requests for opening files is not desirable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist, don't overwrite builtins such as `dict`:

```
data = [{'account': 'xyz', 'email':'abc@xyz.com'}, {'account': 'xyz', 'email':'zxc@vbn.com'}, {'account': 'qwe', 'email':'rty@uio.com'}, ..., ...]
```

If you don't need to keep a grouped collection of the accounts/emails you can just use a dictionary to keep each file open and linked to an email, then close the files after:

```
files = {}
for account, email in map(dict.values, data):
    files.setdefault(account, open(f'{account}.txt', 'w')).write(f'{email},')
for file in files.values(): file.close()
```

Alternatively, you can use `collections.defaultdict` to group the emails:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)
for account, email in map(dict.values, data):
    grouped[account].append(email)

for account, emails in grouped.items():
    with open(f'{account}.txt') as f:
        f.writelines(f'{email},' for email in emails)
```

Comment: I already have them sorted based on the frequency of each account. I am just curious to know why I would need to group them?

Comment: In your first solution, it seems like you are opening the file multiple times. Is there any way I could write the emails to a string or a list and then open the file for an account once and write them together?

Comment: I'm not grouping them in my first example, they don't even need to be sorted in either of my examples. Only if using `itertools.groupby` vs `collections.defaultdict` would they need to be sorted.

Comment: @jmrjmr I am not opening files multiple times in my first example. The purpose of the dict is so it doesn't open multiple times. `dict.setdefault` will only call the default function if the valuse doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you. I tried your first approach but I am getting this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) on the second line

Comment: See my edit, I wrote `items` not `values`, I finally was able to test the code as my computer at work is very slow.

Comment: this works, thank you so much! The only thing that I forgot to mention that in each csv file, the first line has to say 'email' in it. How do I accomplish that, without overwriting?

Comment: For the first example, make a function that opens the file, writes the first line and returns the file. use that function in place of where I just open the file. For the second example, just do all that in the loop.